# Determining the time complexities of worst case algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Do the two algorithms have the same theta characterization of Θ(n^2)?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++ )
        sum++;

int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

If not then does this mean that this characterization is not Θ(n^3)?

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for ( int j = 0; j < i * i; j++ )
        for ( int k = 0; k < j; k++ )
            sum++;
```

Comment: I dont think is for the first one but it is n^2 for j<i but I don't know why

Comment: how would you count the the steps taken for either of the two?

Comment: for the 2nd one, there are a total 8 ops? sum = 0 and i = 0 is 2 ops. in the outer loop i<n and i++ is 2(n+1)? for inner loop, 3(n-1) and then +1 for sum++. Im kinda confused in counting the things inside the loops. It has something to do with the hanshake formula n(n+1)/2?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about counting `i = 0`, `sum = 0`, etc. The most important thing here is to count how many times `sum++` runs.

Comment: The only operation you have to count is `sum++`.  In the first case, if n is 10, what will sum be? Look carefully at the loops.  In the second case, if N is 4, what is the behavior of the 'j' loop?

Comment: BTW: The sum indictaes the order.  try n = 100, what sum do you get? if its aroung 10^2 => O(n) , 10^4 => O(n^2), 10^6 => O(n^3) etc. Doesn't work in all cases, but you example is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dan, For the first one did you really mean `j < n * n` rather than `j < n`? If so, the time complexity of the first one is Θ(n^3), isn't it?

If you meant `j < n`, then I believe the first two are both Θ(n^2): The first one takes n^2 steps, and the second one takes 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2 which is Θ(n^2).

I'm thinking the 3rd one is Θ(n^4), but it's harder to prove. Definitely O(n^4).

Comment: yes i did mean j<n*n. the first 2 are the same algorithms besides the inner loop comparison. I knew that the second one was Θ(n^2) but not when there was a multiplcation involved such as the first and third algorithm. So does this mean that the multiplication increases the degree by 1?

Comment: @Dan The multiplication increases the degree by n, not 1.   `for(int i=0;i<n*n;i++)` loops n^2 times.  @larsH Θ(n^4) indeed.

Comment: @Tony when @Dan said degree I believe he was talking about the exponent. So yes @Dan if you multiply n^k * n, you get n^(k+1). I'm not sure if that's what you're asking though.